# how to pass multiple parameters through jquery to php

Tags: php, jquery, parameter-passing, contenteditable

I'm using the contenteditable feature, I am trying to update multiple fields, however when I try to pass through 2 fields this does not seem to work, it works perfectly with one. When I click the save button I don't even get an error message.

I believe I am not passing the data through correctly and this is because of my lack of knowledge.

```
index.php

<?php
        //get data from database.
        include("db.php");
        $sql = mysql_query("select * from datadump where id='1'");
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);     ?>
<div id="wrap">
    <header><h1>Contenteditable Database driven</h1></header>

    <div id="status"></div>

    <div id="maincontent">

    <div id="editable" contentEditable="true">
<?php
        echo $row['content'];
    ?>      
    </div>  
    <div id="editablea" contentEditable="true">
    <?php
        echo $row['name'];
    ?>
    </div>
    <button id="save">Save</button>
    </div>
```

js/js.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#save").click(function (e) {         
        var content = $('#editable').html();    
    var name = $('editablea').html();

        $.ajax({
            url: '/save.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
            content: content,
            name: editablea
            },              
            success:function (data) {

                if (data == '1')
                {
                    $("#status")
                    .addClass("success")
                    .html("Data saved successfully")
                    .fadeIn('fast')
                    .delay(3000)
                    .fadeOut('slow');   
                }
                else
                {
                    $("#status")
                    .addClass("error")
                    .html("An error occured, the data could not be saved")
                    .fadeIn('fast')
                    .delay(3000)
                    .fadeOut('slow');   
                }
            }
        });   

    });

    $("#maincontent").click(function (e) {
        $("#save").show();
        e.stopPropagation();
    });

    $(document).click(function() {
        $("#save").hide();  
    });

});
```

save.php

```
<?php
include("db.php");
$content = $_POST['content'];
$name = $_POST['editablea'];//get posted data
$content = mysql_real_escape_string($content);  //escape string 

$sql = "UPDATE datadump SET content = '$content', name = '$name' WHERE id = '1' ";

if (mysql_query($sql))
{
    echo 1;
}
 ?>
```

Comment: in your data you have variable named content and editablea but i don't  see any variable editablea,instead you should be using name is guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
data: {
            content: content,
            name: editablea
            },
```

Try:

```
data: {
            contentLabel: content,
            nameLabel: name
            },
```

edittablea is not a defined javascript variable.

```
     $("#save").click(function (e) {         
            var content = $('#editable').val();    
            var name = $('#editablea').val();
            alert(content); 
            alert(name);

            $.ajax({
                url: 'save.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                contentLabel: content,
                nameLabel: name
                },              
                success:function (data) {

     //save.php
    <?php
    $content = $_POST['contentLabel'];
    $name = $_POST['nameLabel'];
```

**Also, if save.php is located in the same folder as your ajax calling script, then you don't need the slash in front of /save.php**

Comment: this didn't work, however it did enable the error message to display I also changed in my php file $name= $_POST['editablea']; to $name = $_POST['name']; still did not update the database

Comment: It should be $name=$_POST['nameLabel']; Use Firebug to see the data you are actually POSTing to your Ajaqx script

Comment: I tried that too and this stopped the error message displaying, the code allows me to pass through the "content" change but not the "name" change. I changed the var name = $('#editablea').html(); to say var nameLabel and this still did not work, so im quite confused as to why it doesnt work

Comment: You're confusing the syntax of preparing your data to pass to the php script. I am editing my question to make this clearer

Comment: i've done as you have suggested and this still fails :( why is that I can pass the "content" through but not the name, I've used the same process, var content= $('#editable').html(); to get the data from this div and have tried to use the same process to get the data in editablea. i dont get why i cant do it even when using your process

Comment: I'd say that has to do with what's being put into those variables. Edit your original question to include the contents of `var content` and `var name` - you can view that content by typing `console.log(content)` and `console.log(name)` right after you define those variables. Then use Firebug's console (or Chrome's equivilant) to view the contents of those variables, and include them in your original question.

Comment: i have no idea how to use console.log? @J. Robertson

Comment: I just edited my code to have javascript pop up those variables. At some point, if you're working with jQuery, you really need to google Firebug and using console.log(). It will make debugging javascript enormously easier.

Comment: oh ok I will get on to researching firebug, also I did the alert for the name field and it comes back as "undefined"

Comment: why does it say "undefined", I've defined this in the same way as the content @J. Robertson

Comment: Ok - try the revision I just made to my answer above. instead of doing `var content = $('#editable').html();` I did `var content = $('#editable').val();` It sounds like your variables aren't getting valid data

Comment: this still doesn't work still getting the undefined alert @J. Robertson

Comment: oh good grief. I see the problem. inside the var name definition, we're missing a # sign. jQuery doesn't know which element we're trying to fetch. fixed my answer

Comment: no thats not the problem, I didn't copy and paste your code I typed this and included the hash

Comment: Just so I'm clear - alert(content) is outputting something, but alert(name) is not?

Comment: Check your page source inside the `<div id="editablea"> </div>` after the page loads. Make sure there's something for jQuery to grab.

Comment: that's fine. inspecting your "editablea" div and make sure there's something in that div

Comment: the alert is bringing back some data now, I retyped the line, there must have been some extra whitespace or hidden characters or something in there which caused it to come back undefined. however this is not updating the sql table :S @j. robertson

Comment: That's a whole nother question. If this solved your problem - which I think it did - please mark this as the answer and create a new question.

Comment: lol ok thanks for your help any mate very much appreciated, ill post this question later, ill try to figure it out on my own first will be a good test

Comment: Good attitude! Good luck, and I'm glad I was able to help!